# How to get the first match word before a match

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a huge text that i need delimit.

```
STARTING
....
TEXT
....
END
STARTING
....
TEXT
....
END
```

All e that i want delimite start and end with the same characters. But i just want get the text if between the start and end, the `ID: 10` appears. Sample:

```
STARTING
....
TEXT
....
END
STARTING
....
TEXT
ID: 10
....
END
```

Desire result:

```
STARTING
....
TEXT
ID: 10
....
END
```

So, i made this regex:

```
START[\s\S]*?ID:\s15[\s\S]*?END
```

http://regexr.com/3fa8s

The problem is: The match is getting the text before, when it should get:

```
START
ID: 15
END
```

Is getting:

```
START
ID: 13
END
START
ID: 15
END
```

Is it possible to get the first `START` before the match?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Temper" the `[\s\S]` pattern with a `(?!START)` lookahead:

```
START(?:(?!START)[\s\S])*?ID:\s15[\s\S]*?END
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexr.com/3fa8v)

The `(?:(?!START)[\s\S])*?` will match any char (`[\s\S]`), 0 or more occurrences but as few as possible, that is not starting a `START` sequence.

The lazy `*?` quantifier can be turned into a greedy one, but you need to add more alternatives into the lookahead then:

```
START(?:(?!START|END|ID:\s15)[\s\S])*ID:\s15[\s\S]*?END
```

See [another regex demo](http://regexr.com/3fa95)

Answer (score 0):

Pattern `[\s\S]` doesn't make sense, it's equivalent to `.`:

- `\s` - whitespace
- `\S` - non-whitespace
- `[\s\S]` - whitespace or non-whitespace, so everything basically, equivalent to `.`.

What you probably need is simple regexp:

`/START\s+ID:\s+15\s+END/gm`

...which is matching your single "record" with id 15.

But you're also saying that you have "(...) a huge text you want to delimit (...)". This contradicts a bit your following example. If you want to get each record, which is probably what you need, really, try using:

`/START\s+ID:\s+(\d)+\s+END/gm`